# KiCAD merge two different copper planes together

Tags: kicad

I have a design with different copper planes, for example, a ground plane and a `VS` copper, on the bottom size.

[image]

But KiCAD overlays both copper planes and throws some design rule errors:

[image]

So what is wrong with both copper layers?

Comment: Check if both planes have the correct priority. Say, `vs`has a hjgher priority than `GND`.

Comment: You are right. This was the mistake. Thought KiCAD will handle this automatically. Write it as answer, please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the priority of both planes are not set properly. Double check it and make sure that `vs` has a higher priority than `GND`.